# .htaccess repeatedly asks for username/password

Tags: htaccess

I'm trying to add password protection to my personal website using `.htpasswd` and `.htaccess`. When I enter the username and password, I get asked again and again. How do I resolve this?

---

.htpasswd

```
st:((encrypted pw))
```

.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Both files are in the root directory. This is the first website I'm building, so I'm no expert.

---

Edit: I used [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) tool to create my .htpasswd file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
> ```
>
> Both files are in the root directory.

The `AuthUserFile` directive takes an absolute filesystem path (or a path that is relative to the *server root*), not a path relative to the *document root* - which is what `/.htpasswd` looks like? It is unlikely that your "root directory" (by which I assume you mean your website's `DocumentRoot`) is in the root of your server (if it is then you should probably change it).

You'd expect this to be something like:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/secure/.htpasswd
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. How do I find the absolute path to a given directory?

Comment: What sort of server/hosting/control panel (eg. cPanel) and/or server-side scripting language are you using? If you know the _document root_ then you can work it out. Ideally, `.htpasswd` files should be stored _above_ the document root (although they often default to being stored in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file).

Comment: That was the problem: I didn't know my document root. But I've found a way to find it out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079479/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-public-html-folder) and now it works! Thank you so much for the hint!